# Enabling import/export .FBX addon

Tags: add-on, import

I have *User Preferences --> Addons --> Import-Export: Autodesk FBX Format* checked, but .FBX does not show up in  *File --> Import*.
Is there something else I need to do to enable this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Did you click "Save User Preferences"?  If so, it should be under File --> Import --> FBX (.fbx)

Comment: Thank you for the responses.

I have done:

File --> User Preferences --> Save User Settings

Should that be sufficient or is there something else I need to do?

Comment: @DrMark Strange. That add-on is normally automatically included and enabled in Blender. Is it possible that you accidentally disabled it because it was already enabled?

Comment: Just to make sure I enabled *everything* (for some reason 'Nodes Efficiency Tools' wouldn't enable) and I restarted Blender.
I still see 'Autodesk FBX (.fbx)' on under 'export' but not under 'import'.
I didn't see any Autodesk entries under 'import' - lots of import types
but not that one.

FYI: I'm running Blender 2.67b under Windows 7 Enterprise.

Answer (score 0):

The fix was to upgrade to version 3.77. The DBX addons worked fine after that.